# Karate Gatling performance tests does not run if any API tests fail in feature file

Tags: karate

For my karate DSL repo for API tests, I am running regression tests and performance tests together. Performance tests are needed for only a small subset of the regression set and I am using a tag to identify those. Below is the command I am using-

mvn test -Dtest=RunnerName -Dgatling.simulationClass=mock.SimulationClass

I am noticing that

1. performance tests are not getting triggered if there are any failures in the regression tests covered by mentioned runner. There is no error thrown in relation to performance tests.
2. If all the regression tests pass, then performance tests also get triggered.
3. Performance tests work fine if I trigger the simulation class as a standalone.

Is this working as expected?

Comment: sounds like an issue with your maven setup. insufficient data to diagnose

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas. I have narrowed down the issue further when retrying. In our runner we are asserting that there are no failures in tests.
```
assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
```
As this assertion is failing, tests are stopped. I commented out this assertion, and performance tests got triggered even after failure on another tests. Any thoughts if this is designed behaviour?

Comment: no, but isn't this expected and just normal JUnit behavior ? your question may not have anything to do with karate

Comment: Agreed @PeterThomas. I think i would trigger the performance tests separately in that case, as QA environments are bug prone, unless you have any additional inputs to trigger the performance tests irrespective of functional results?

Comment: I would just trigger it from CI via a maven (or gradle) command on the command-line. the docs have some tips: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#maven

Comment: Thanks, @PeterThomas. That's what I am using.